# проверка значения в строчке бд

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = $db->query('UPDATE `items` SET `status` = '.$db->quote($user['accid']).' WHERE `status` = 1 AND `id` = '.$db->quote($value));
            if ($sql->rowCount() !== 1) {
                exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'error1')));
            }
```

Как в строчке `if ($sql->rowCount() !== 1) {` добавить еще одну проверку на значение `check` в строчке бд. Типо `if ($sql->rowCount() !== 1 && $sql->... check == 1) {`. Нужна именно проверка на значение check.

Comment: Невозможно. Только новым запросом. Хотя на самом деле - бессмысленно. Ну то есть в результате нет смысла.

Comment: Как именно это сделать? мне нужна проверка, чтобы условие выполнялось только если в этой строке значение check == 1

Comment: Простите, но Ваше желание лишено физического смысла. Запись уже обновлена, поздно пить боржоми... а у количества изменённых запросом записей (а вовсе даже не у самих записей) нет никакого `check`.

Comment: Ну а как тогда подобное реализовать вообще? Мб другое решение есть?

Comment: Как реализовать нечто бессмысленное... гениально! Наверное, Вам нужно просто успокоиться и понять, что нужно Вам вовсе не то, что Вы пока что себе представляете. И сосредоточиться не на поиске решения, а на понимании задачи. И только когда оно появится...

Comment: PS. А ещё сдаётся мне, что Вам надо нечто эдакое дополнительно проверять ДО обновления. Если так - Вам повезло. Альтернатива ещё хуже - отобрать кандидатов на обновление, проверить, и только если проверка ОК, то обновлять.

Comment: Если нужно обновить запись после обновления другой записи, то добавьте триггер

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы выполнялось условие в PHP то можно добавить тригерам, который в случае чего делает откат обновления. Если же нужно, чтобы запись вставлялась только если check = 1, то это условие нужно прописать как where у запроса

Comment: Не очень понимаю как именно это сделать? Можно пример?